# What is a good algorithm for getting the minimum vertex cover of a tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree, dynamic-programming

What is a good algorithm for getting the minimum vertex cover of a tree?

#### INPUT:

The node's neighbours.

#### OUTPUT:

The minimum number of vertices.

Comment: Sounds like revising for an exam and "not finding" the lecture notes.

Comment: +1 just for stumping the great and mighty Welbog.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I hope [here](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=NSfIWxqPlbcC&pg=PA337&lpg=PA337&dq=tree+vertex+cover&source=bl&ots=xZog0E6LaL&sig=QluBgt6OcdY0UDh2qPQiA68CCO0&hl=en&ei=axYgSp2VHcuvsgbEpti5Bg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1) you can find more related answer to your question.

---

I was thinking about my solution, probably you will need to polish it but as long as dynamic programing is in one of your tags you probably need to:

1. For each u vertex define S+(u) is
   cover size with vertex u and S-(u)
   cover without vertex u.
2. S+(u)= 1 + Sum(S-(v)) for each child v of u.
3. S-(u)=Sum(max{S-(v),S+(v)}) for each child v of u.
4. Answer is max(S+(r), S-(r)) where r is root of your tree.

---

After reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_independent_set). Changed the above algorithm to find maximum independent set, since in wiki article stated

> A set is independent if and only if its complement is a vertex cover.

So by changing min to max we can find the maximum independent set and by compliment the minimum vertex cover, since both problem are equivalent.

Comment: it dosen't help much,I'm looking for a pseudocode or a more detailed explanation on the algorithm

Comment: You need to find a way to somehow count the size of cover using information of each vertex, therefore define for each vertex variable which will count for you size there vertex included or not, generally described algorithm will return you the size value, but you can easily extend it to build a sort of the table there you will store your choice at each step.

Comment: it dosen't necessarily need to be dynamic-programming

Comment: so perform exhaustive search. I think you are looking for more effective way, so it would be a dynamic programming.

Comment: I didn't tell nobody "do it differently",I'm just tring to figure out the simplest way to do it, no matter the complexity,but back-tracking is to much

Comment: Finding minimum vertex cover is one of the hardest problem in CS, therefore it's could be efficiently solvable only for few cases, so to simplify and optimize it dynamic programing could be very useful, since it could give you solution in less time complexity than most over approaches. I'm not sure you will find another way to optimize it rather than backtracking. And read this, it could help you http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming.

Comment: I still don't get something ,If I have a node(u) who has two leafs as children,then both children will have S+(v1)=1 , S-(v1)=0( S+(v2)=1 S-(v2)=0) so (u) will have S+(u)=1+S-(v1)+S-(v2)=1 and S-(u)=0,what am I doing wrong ?,a simple exemple will be welcomed

Comment: "Finding minimum vertex cover is one of the hardest problem in CS, therefore it's could be efficiently solvable only for few cases ",I know that finding a minimum cover is a NP-complete problem if I'm looking for the minimum cover for a graph,but my case is simpler as I'm looking for the minimum cover of a tree

Comment: That the reason you can compute it efficiently, only because you can use the recursive structure of the tree. I give you a simple example:
vertex v has two children u1 and u2. S+(u1)=S+(u2)=1 and S-(u1)=S-(u2)=0, so S+(u)=1, S-(u)=2, therefore solution is min{1,2}. You can deduce from it vertex cover is only v and has size of 1.

Comment: BTW, the recursive structure of the tree is definitely pointing on backtracking solution.

Comment: how come S-(u) is 2 when above you wrote that S-(u)=Sum(min{S-(v),S+(v)}).isn't it max{S-(v),S+(v)}

Comment: I think I have a mistake, need to think and I'll update my post.

Comment: I've a reduction to slight different problem, but once you solve it it will solve also the original one.

Comment: there still is a mistake,changing only min to max won't help ,for example:       
                            (3)(4)
                              |
                            (3)(1)
                    |         |         |
                 (0)(1)     (0)(1)    (0)(1)     

the example is the following format (S-v)(S+v) and max(S+(r), S-(r)) (where r is the root) is 4,which is obiously wrong

Comment: it didn't format the example right,the root (3,4) has a child(3,1) wich has 3 children (0,1) (0,1) (0,1)

Comment: As I said now it solves different problem. After you will do the compliment it will give you the solution to the vertex cover problem.

Comment: what do you mean by "do the compliment" ?

Comment: Now, my solution will give you the maximum independent set of vertexes, by statement I've wrote above, the complement of this set is minimum vertex cover, by definition given from wiki.

Answer (score 18):

I didn't fully understand after reading the answers here, so I thought I'd post one from [here](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/spring11/lectures/lec21.pdf)

The general idea is that you root the tree at an arbitrary node, and ask whether that root is in the cover or not. If it is, then you calculate the min vertex cover of the subtrees rooted at its children by recursing. If it isn't, then every child of the root must be in the vertex cover so that every edge between the root and its children is covered. In this case, you recurse on the root's grandchildren.

So for example, if you had the following tree:

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
 / \ / \
D  E F  G
```

Note that by inspection, you know the min vertex cover is `{B, C}`. We will find this min cover.

Here we start with `A`.

### A is in the cover

We move down to the two subtrees of `B` and `C`, and recurse on this algorithm. We can't simply state that `B` and `C` are not in the cover, because even if `AB` and `AC` are covered, we can't say anything about whether we will need `B` and `C` to be in the cover or not.

(Think about the following tree, where both the root and one of its children are in the min cover (`{A, D}`)

```
  A
 /|\___
B C    D
      /|\
     E F G
```

)

### A is not in the cover

But we know that `AB` and `AC` must be covered, so we have to add `B` and `C` to the cover. Since `B` and `C` are in the cover, we can recurse on their children instead of recursing on `B` and `C` (even if we did, it wouldn't give us any more information).

### "Formally"

Let `C(x)` be the size of the min cover rooted at `x`.

Then,

```
C(x) = min ( 
            1 + sum ( C(i) for i in x's children ),                    // root in cover
            len(x's children) + sum( C(i) for i in x's grandchildren)  // root not in cover
            )
```

Answer (score 12):

T(V,E) is a tree, which implies that for any leaf, any minimal vertex cover has to include either the leaf or the vertex adjacent to the leaf. This gives us the following algorithm to finding S, the vertex cover:

1. Find all leaves of the tree (BFS or DFS), O(|V|) in a tree.
2. If (u,v) is an edge such that v is a leaf, add u to the vertex cover, and prune (u,v). This will leave you with a forest T_1(V_1,E_1),...,T_n(U_n,V_n).
3. Now, if V_i={v}, meaning |V_i|=1, then that tree can be dropped since all edges incident on v are covered. This means that we have a termination condition for a recursion, where we have either one or no vertices, and we can compute *S_i* as the cover for each *T_i*, and define S as all the vertices from step 2 union the cover of each *T_i*.

Now, all that remains is to verify that if the original tree has only one vertex, we return 1 and never start the recursion, and the minimal vertex cover can be computed.

**Edit:**

Actually, after thinking about it for a bit, it can be accomplished with a simple DFS variant.

Comment: No one really cared about this answer? I think this is much better than the answer marked as it is much simpler

Answer (score 2):

```
{- Haskell implementation of Artem's algorithm -}

data Tree = Branch [Tree]
    deriving Show

{- first int is the min cover; second int is the min cover that includes the root -}
minVC :: Tree -> (Int, Int)
minVC (Branch subtrees) = let
    costs = map minVC subtrees
    minWithRoot = 1 + sum (map fst costs) in
    (min minWithRoot (sum (map snd costs)), minWithRoot)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use a DFS based algorithm to solve this probelm:

```
DFS(node x)
{

    discovered[x] = true;

    /* Scan the Adjacency list for the node x*/
    while((y = getNextAdj() != NULL)
    {

        if(discovered[y] == false)
        {

            DFS(y);

           /* y is the child of node x*/
           /* If child is not selected as a vertex for minimum selected cover
            then select the parent */ 
           if(y->isSelected == false)
           {
               x->isSelected = true;
           }
        }
   }
}
```

The leaf node will never be selected for the vertex cover.

Answer (score 2):

We need to find the minimum vertex cover for each node we have to choices to make, either to include it or not to include it. But according to the problem for each edge (u, v), either of 'u' or 'v' should be in the cover so we need to take care that if the current vertex is not included then we should include its children, and if we are including the current vertex then, we may or may not include its children based on optimal solution.

Here, DP1[v] for any vertex v = When we include it.
DP2[v] for any vertex v = when we don't include it.

DP1[v] = 1 + sum(min(DP2[c], DP1[c])) - this means include current and may or may not include its children, based on what is optimal.

DP2[v] = sum(DP1[c]) - this means not including current then we need to include children of current vertex. Here, c is the child of vertex v.

Then, our solution is min(DP1[root], DP2[root])

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<vector<int> > g;

int dp1[100010], dp2[100010];

void dfs(int curr, int p){
    for(auto it : g[curr]){
        if(it == p){
            continue;
        }
        dfs(it, curr);
        dp1[curr] += min(dp1[it], dp2[it]);
        dp2[curr] += dp1[it];
    }
    dp1[curr] += 1;
}

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    g.resize(n+1);
    for(int i=0 ; i<n-1 ; i++){
        int u, v;
        cin >> u >> v;
        g[u].push_back(v);
        g[v].push_back(u);
    }
    dfs(1, 0);
    cout << min(dp1[1], dp2[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use a linear program to solve the minimum vertex cover problem.
A formulation as an integer linear program could look like the one given here: [ILP formulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover#ILP_formulation)

I don't think that your own implementation would be faster than these highly optimized LP solvers.