# Is there an specific algorithm or way to solve this special tree problem?

Tags: algorithm, methods, tree, binary-tree, traversal

For example, I mark the node A in this binary tree. The nodes next to node A will also be marked at the same time. And I want to output the minimum nodes like A so I can mark all the nodes of the binary tree.
Is there any specific algorithm for these kind of question? Or any ideas to solve this question?

The scenario when I mark A:

[image: picture 1]

All nodes will get marked when A&B are marked:

[image: picture 2]

The output of this example should be 2.

Comment: Post the images directly in the question not as imgur links.

Comment: this is known as minimum vertex cover and is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926847/what-is-a-good-algorithm-for-getting-the-minimum-vertex-cover-of-a-tree#13370734

Answer (score 0):

If the tree is not too big, the easiest method seems to be to start from the root, and apply it recursively. Instead of thinking of "marking", it might help to think of it more as a "deleting", while keeping count. There are at most three ways to remove the root, so you just try them:

- remove the root and its left and right node, calculate the sum of the marks for the remaining trees, call this number a
- if present, remove the node left below the root and its neighbors, calculate the sum of the marks for the remaining trees, call this number b
- if present, remove the node right below the root and its neighbors, calculate the sum of the marks for the remaining trees, call this number b
- the minimal number of marks is `minmum(a, b, c) + 1`